# como cargar MenuBar con FXMLloader

Tags: javafx

hola estoy tratando cargar un menubar llamando al archivo visualizar.fxml, como hago para cargar el menubar, en la misma escena o stage que el documento, que puedo corregir, soy algo primerizo en esto, y necesito una orientacion. aca les dejo mi codigo. gracias:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{

    primaryStage.setTitle("THANOS V1.0 ");
    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Visualizar.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,  Color.WHITE);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();//Barramenu
    BorderPane raiz = new BorderPane();
    raiz.setTop(menuBar);
    Menu Agregar = new Menu("Archivo"); //creando Menu archivo
    MenuItem PrimerItem= new MenuItem("Agregar Datos"); //creando menu item
    Agregar.getItems().addAll(PrimerItem);
    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(Agregar);



}
```

Answer (score 1):

> como hago para cargar el `menubar`

Según se muestra tu código, el contenedor principal es el `AnchorPane`.
Tendrás que crear el `MenuBar` y añadirlo al `root` antes de añadir este contendor principal a la `scene`.

También para **agregar ese menubar al root** basta con hacer esto..

```
root.getChildren().add(menuBar);
```

Te dejo el método `start()`

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("THANOS V1.0");
        //AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        AnchorPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));      

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();//Barramenu

        Menu agregar = new Menu("Archivo");//Creando menu archivo
        MenuItem primerItem = new MenuItem("Agregar Datos"); //creando menu item
        agregar.getItems().add(primerItem);
        menuBar.getMenus().add(agregar);

        root.getChildren().add(menuBar);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

**Resultado**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Para más información de como trabaja el *layout AnchorPane* y como situar los elementos de su interior en la [**Documentación**](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html)